# android client & windows server

Tags: android, lan, service-discovery

I have a running server on my LAN and an android app that needs to socket connect to that server. My problem right now is that the server's ip is changing (for some good reasons, I can't make it static).

Is there any way to "auto discover" the server without using ddns? this system works only in LAN and both parties (windows server and android client) are in the same subnet.

Thanks

Comment: why dont you want ddns? Do the devices have internet connection?

Comment: no, none of those devices have internet connection.

Comment: Then what are the good reasons for not making it static, that should be an easy configuration on the router.

Comment: I just can't. :) Is not about complexity ... is a company rule thing regarding this server.

Comment: Well I guess you are left with the only option of broadcasting the LAN using the subnet, though that is probably not allowed either. Not an easy setup to work with you got there :)

Comment: Yes broadcasting is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now knowing that:

- Both parties do not have internet
- DDns is not an option
- Broadcasting not allowed

The only option left is, when the android fails to connect to the server, try talking with every found ip on LAN one-by-one until someone respond.

This should of course be done in a fashion so that only your server would respond correctly.

As you are on a LAN this loss in connection should happen very rarely, if ever, unless server is restartet. Though, that depends on the LAN setup.